# Python regex: alternative positive lookbehind assertion

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex expression which is meant to find the "IF" keyword (case insensitive) in a string. Some constraints are imposed:

- It should be preceded by a whitespace or a ) character (from a previous expression)
- It should be followed by whitespace or ( character

The below expression accomplishes these constraints. However, this expression does not find the keyword when it's located at the start of a string (`if(foo, 1, 2)` for instance).

Using something like `^|(?<=[\s\)])(?i)if(?=[\s\(])` does not seem to work. I tried `?:^|[\s\)])` but that seems to also capture the space in front of the keyword.

This is what I have so far:

```
(?<=[\s\)])(?i)if(?=[\s\(])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an alternation group with two zero-width assertions:

```
(?i)(?:^|(?<=[\s)]))if(?=[\s(])
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XC94CU/1).

Here, `(?:^|(?<=[\s)]))` matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[\s)])` - a location that is immediately preceded with a whitespace or `)` character.

Note that the `(?i)` inline case insensitive modifier in a Python `re` regex affects the whole pattern regardless of where it is located in it, so I suggest moving it to the pattern start for better visibility.

Also, there is no need to escape `(` and `)` inside character classes, `[...]` constructs, as they are treated as literal parentheses inside them.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments and corrections.

Comment: BTW, `(?i)(?:^|(?<=[\s)]))if(?=[\s(])` = `(?i)(?<![^\s)])if(?=[\s(])`, though the second variant is a bit more cryptic due to double negation. The functionality is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `|` is applied at top level, so it is an alteration between:
`^` and `(?<=[\s\)])(?i)if(?=[\s\(])`.

Just add non-capturing group around `^` and `(?<=[\s\)])`:

`(?:^|(?<=[\s\)]))(?i)if(?=[\s\(])`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem (for this particular case that only involves single characters) using a double negation:

```
(?<![^\s)])
```

(not preceded by a character that is not a whitespace nor a closing parenthesis). This condition includes the start of the string too.